# Counting Records the Pass Over Midnight

Tags: sas

I have two datasets:

1) Let's call the fist data set - "Provider". It contains a year's list of providers (over 3900 shifts/records), the date which they worked a shift and the shift type. Note that there are shift types that span over midnight.

```
          Date             Provider        Shift
          1/8/2019           Bob           ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B)
          1/10/2019          Bob           ED C/D 11p-7a (ED C/D)
          1/16/2019          Bob           ED C 3p-12a (ED C)
          1/9/2019           Sue           UMC 5p-2a (UMC)
          1/11/2019          Bob           ED C/D 11p-7a (ED C/D)
          1/13/2019          Bob           ED PH/night 10p-4a (ED PH/night)
```

2) I have another data set - "Patients". It contains the year's worth of FINs, date/time when they saw a provider, and the name of the provider they saw of all patients seen at our location.

```
            FIN        Date               Provider Name
             1      1/8/2019 23:40           Bob 
             2      1/9/2019 01:46           Timbo
             3      1/9/2019 01:30           Bob
             4      1/9/2019 05:06           Patty
             5      1/9/2019 02:50           Bob
             6      1/9/2019 17:23           Sue
             7      1/9/2019 06:45           Mike
             8      1/10/2019 01:35          Sue
```

I'm looking to create a new data set that contains the number of patients seen during a given shift.

So for example the data set would look like this:

```
             Shift date    Shift                         FIN             Provider 
              1/8/2019     ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B)         1                Bob
              1/8/2019     ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B)         3                Bob
              1/8/2019     ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B)         5                Bob
              1/9/2019     UMC 5p-2a (UMC)                6                Sue
              1/9/2019     UMC 5p-2a (UMC)                8                Sue
```

I could very easily create this data set by merging the two data sets then matching based on date and provider name; however, as I mentioned before, some of the shifts span past midnight so I am unable to match by date.

There are roughly 20 different shift types I'm interested in gathering data for, of which 6 span over midnight. I would need to structure my data so that say if a provider worked the ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B) shift on 1/8/2019 then count any patient who he/she also saw before 7am on 1/9/2019? If possible, I would then need to create some sort of macro (I think).

Hope this makes sense - thanks for help!

Comment: In your final data, why is FIN=2 attributed to Bob instead of Timbo ?  Should the FINs be 1,3,5,6,8 ?

Comment: @Richard, yes you are correct, my mistake and I have fixed this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to process the `Provider` data to compute shift start and end datetimes.  This will require locating the *`##p-##a`*, and, presumably, also *`##a-##a`* , *`##a-##p`* and *`##p-##p`* text portions in `Shift`.

After the shift datetimes are computed the data can be joined in this manner:

```
  patients
join 
  provider
on
  patients.date between provider.shift_start and provider.shift_end
& patients.provider = provider.provider
```

**Example**

```
data provider;
attrib
  date informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10.
  provider length=$10
  shift length=$60
;
input date& provider& shift&; datalines;
1/8/2019     Bob     ED A/B 11p-7a (ED A/B)
1/10/2019    Bob     ED C/D 11p-7a (ED C/D)
1/16/2019    Bob     ED C 3p-12a (ED C)
1/9/2019     Sue     UMC 5p-2a (UMC)
1/11/2019    Bob     ED C/D 11p-7a (ED C/D)
1/13/2019    Bob     ED PH/night 10p-4a (ED PH/night)
1/15/2019    Bob     ED PH/night 10p-9p (ED PH/night)
1/17/2019    Bob     ED PH/night 2-11a (ED PH/night)
;

data patients;
attrib
  fin length=8
  service_dt length=8 format=datetime20. informat=anydtdtm20.
  provider length=$10
;
input FIN&  service_dt&  Provider&; datalines;
1   1/8/2019 23:40     Bob 
2   1/9/2019 01:46     Timbo
3   1/9/2019 01:30     Bob
4   1/9/2019 05:06     Patty
5   1/9/2019 02:50     Bob
6   1/9/2019 17:23     Sue
7   1/9/2019 06:45     Mike
8   1/10/2019 01:35    Sue
;

* compute shift start and end datetimes;
* presume the shift time ranges are valid;
* this example does not deal with start and ends at noon or midnight; 
data provider_range;
  set provider;

  rxid = prxparse('/(\d{1,2})(a|p)-(\d{1,2})(a|p)/');

  if prxmatch(rxid,shift) then do;
    length t1 $2 p1 $1 t2 $2 p2 $1;
    t1 = prxposn(rxid,1,shift);  t1n=input(t1,2.);
    p1 = prxposn(rxid,2,shift);
    t2 = prxposn(rxid,3,shift);  t2n=input(t2,2.);
    p2 = prxposn(rxid,4,shift);

    select (p1||p2);
      when ('aa', 'pp') do;
              shift_start = dhms(date, t1n+12*(p2='p'),0,0);
              shift_end   = dhms(date, t2n+12*(p2='p'),0,0);
            end;
      when ('ap') do;
              shift_start = dhms(date, t1n+0,0,0);
              shift_end   = dhms(date, t2n+12,0,0);
            end;
      otherwise /* pa */ do;
              shift_start = dhms(date, t1n+12,0,0);
              shift_end   = dhms(date, t2n+24,0,0);
            end;
    end;
  end;
  else do;
    put 'ERROR: Invalid shift, '  shift ;
    delete;
  end;

  format shift_start shift_end datetime20.;
  drop rxid t1: p1: t2: p2:;
run;

* this join does not use SAS SQL BETWEEN, the join criteria 
* uses explicit construct  a <= b and b <= c instead;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    provider.date as shift_date,
    provider.shift,
    patients.service_dt,
    patients.fin,
    patients.provider
  from patients
  join provider_range as provider
    on patients.provider = provider.provider and
       provider.shift_start <= patients.service_dt and
       provider.shift_end >= patients.service_dt
  order by
    fin
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to work my way through understanding your solution and found a useful resource below but was wondering if you could comment as to how some of your code works, specifically the prxparse,prxposn, and when ('aa, 'pp')...  https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/265-29.pdf